# Making a simple form type-safe

Tags: haskell, ihp

## Context

I have a simple IHP application which converts farenheit to celsius.

I've stripped out many of the files so that the bulk of the app is in the following file:

https://github.com/dharmatech/ConvertTemperatureIhp/blob/003-type-safe-form-generation/Web/FrontController.hs

The contents of that file are shown here:

```hs
module Web.FrontController where

import IHP.RouterPrelude

import Application.Helper.Controller
import IHP.ControllerPrelude

import IHP.ViewPrelude
import Generated.Types
import Application.Helper.View

data Temperature = Temperature { val :: Float } deriving (Show)

-- renderForm :: Temperature -> Html
-- renderForm temp = formFor temp [hsx|
--     abc
-- |]

instance CanRoute TemperatureController where
    parseRoute' = do
        let form   = string "/Temperature/Form"   <* endOfInput >> pure FormAction
        let result = string "/Temperature/Result" <* endOfInput >> pure ResultAction
        form <|> result

instance HasPath TemperatureController where
    pathTo FormAction   = "/Temperature/Form"
    pathTo ResultAction = "/Temperature/Result"

data WebApplication = WebApplication deriving (Eq, Show)

data TemperatureController
    = FormAction
    | ResultAction
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data)

instance Controller TemperatureController where
   
    action FormAction = respondHtml [hsx|
        <form action={pathTo ResultAction} method="post">
            <label>Farenheit</label>
            <input type="text" name="farenheit"/>
        </form>
    |]

    action ResultAction = 
        let
            farenheit = IHP.ControllerPrelude.param @Float "farenheit"
            celsius = (farenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0
        in
            respondHtml [hsx| 
                <p>Celsius: {celsius}</p>
            |]

instance FrontController WebApplication where
    controllers = 
        [ 
          parseRoute @TemperatureController 
        ]

instance InitControllerContext WebApplication where
    initContext = do
        initAutoRefresh
```

If I go to `http://localhost:8000/Temperature/Form` I get the following page:

[image]

After submitting that form, the following page is shown:

[image]

## Form code

Here's the code that generates the form:

```
action FormAction = respondHtml [hsx|
    <form action={pathTo ResultAction} method="post">
        <label>Farenheit</label>
        <input type="text" name="farenheit"/>
    </form>
|]
```

This code is stringly-typed; i.e. we're referring to the field parameter `"farhenheit"` by name in a string.

I'd like to use `formFor` in order to generate type-safe form code as described here:

https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/form.html

So I added the following record definition to represent the temperature value:

```
data Temperature = Temperature { val :: Float } deriving (Show)
```

However, when I went to build out a `renderForm` function:

```
renderForm :: Temperature -> Html
renderForm temp = formFor temp [hsx|
    ...
|]
```

the following error was the result:

[image]

Text of the error on the console:

```
[5 of 6] Compiling Web.FrontController ( Web/FrontController.hs, interpreted )

Web/FrontController.hs:15:19: error:
    • Could not deduce (HasField "id" Temperature id0)
        arising from a use of ‘formFor’
      from the context: ?context::ControllerContext
        bound by the type signature for:
                   renderForm :: Temperature -> Html
Failed, four modules loaded.
        at Web/FrontController.hs:(15,1)-(17,2)
      The type variable ‘id0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression: formFor temp (mconcat [])
      In an equation for ‘renderForm’:
          renderForm temp = formFor temp (mconcat [])
   |
15 | renderForm temp = formFor temp [hsx|
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

The message makes it sound like an `id` field is expected to be present.

## Question

Is there a good way to use `formFor` to generate this simple form code in a type-safe manner?

The documentation in section [Advanced Forms](https://ihp.digitallyinduced.com/Guide/form.html#advanced-forms) mentions the following:

> You can get very far with the built-in form helpers. But sometimes you might need a very custom functionality which is not easily doable with the form helpers. In this case, we highly recommend not to use the form helpers for that specific case. Don’t fight the tools.

Is this a scenario which is not suited to the form helpers? :-)

## Update - Add an `id` field

Based on the error message mentioning an `id` field, I added an `id` field:

```
data Temperature = Temperature { id :: Int, val :: Float } deriving (Show)
```

Now the error message is:

```
[5 of 6] Compiling Web.FrontController ( Web/FrontController.hs, interpreted )

Web/FrontController.hs:15:19: error:
    • Could not deduce (HasField "meta" Temperature MetaBag)
        arising from a use of ‘formFor’
Failed, four modules loaded.
      from the context: ?context::ControllerContext
        bound by the type signature for:
                   renderForm :: Temperature -> Html
        at Web/FrontController.hs:(15,1)-(17,2)
    • In the expression: formFor temp (mconcat [])
      In an equation for ‘renderForm’:
          renderForm temp = formFor temp (mconcat [])
   |
15 | renderForm temp = formFor temp [hsx|
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

## Update - `meta` field

Based on the message regarding the `meta` field, I added a `meta` field to `Temperature`:

```
data Temperature = Temperature { id :: Int, val :: Float, meta :: MetaBag  } deriving (Show)
```

Now the error message is as follows:

```
[5 of 6] Compiling Web.FrontController ( Web/FrontController.hs, interpreted )

Web/FrontController.hs:15:19: error:
    • Could not deduce (KnownSymbol (GetModelName Temperature))
        arising from a use of ‘formFor’
      from the context: ?context::ControllerContext
Failed, four modules loaded.
        bound by the type signature for:
                   renderForm :: Temperature -> Html
        at Web/FrontController.hs:(15,1)-(17,2)
    • In the expression: formFor temp (mconcat [])
      In an equation for ‘renderForm’:
          renderForm temp = formFor temp (mconcat [])
   |
15 | renderForm temp = formFor temp [hsx|
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

## Update - `GetModelName`

Since the last error message mentioned `GetModelName`, I added the following based on code I saw in the example blog application from the IHP guide:

```
data Temperature = Temperature { 
    id :: Int, 
    val :: Float, 
    meta :: MetaBag 
} deriving (Show)

type instance GetModelName Temperature = "Temperature"
```

and *now* it compiles.

## Update - `renderForm`

So now that the project compiles, I updated `renderForm` as follows:

```
renderForm :: Temperature -> Html
renderForm temp = formFor temp [hsx|
    {textField #val}
|]
```

The next step is, how to actually generate the form code given this new `renderForm` function. Any suggestions are welcome.

## Update - it's working!

The `Temperature` record definition is now:

```hs
data Temperature = Temperature { 
    id :: Int, 
    farenheit :: Float, 
    meta :: MetaBag 
} deriving (Show)
```

`renderForm` is:

```hs
renderForm :: Temperature -> Html
renderForm temp = formFor' temp "/Temperature/Result" [hsx|
    {textField #farenheit}
|]
```

And finally, `FormAction` is:

```hs
    action FormAction = 

        let temp = Temperature { id = 0, farenheit = 100.0, meta = def }

        in
                
        respondHtml [hsx| {renderForm temp} |]
```

And it seems to be working.

## Notes

It's a little awkward to have to add the unused `id` and `meta` fields in `Temperature` just to satisfy the form generation code:

```hs
data Temperature = Temperature { 
    id :: Int, 
    farenheit :: Float, 
    meta :: MetaBag 
} deriving (Show)
```

Ideally we'd be able to leave those out.

If anyone has any suggestions for how to make this more idiomatic, feel free to answer below.

The latest code as reflected in the above notes is at:

https://github.com/dharmatech/ConvertTemperatureIhp/blob/004-renderForm/Web/FrontController.hs

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full working example based on the updates shown above:

```hs
module Web.FrontController where

import IHP.RouterPrelude

import Application.Helper.Controller
import IHP.ControllerPrelude

import IHP.ViewPrelude
import Generated.Types
import Application.Helper.View

data Temperature = Temperature { 
    id :: Int, 
    farenheit :: Float, 
    meta :: MetaBag 
} deriving (Show)

type instance GetModelName Temperature = "Temperature"

renderForm :: Temperature -> Html
renderForm temp = formFor' temp "/Temperature/Result" [hsx|
    {textField #farenheit}
|]

instance CanRoute TemperatureController where
    parseRoute' = do
        let form   = string "/Temperature/Form"   <* endOfInput >> pure FormAction
        let result = string "/Temperature/Result" <* endOfInput >> pure ResultAction
        form <|> result

instance HasPath TemperatureController where
    pathTo FormAction   = "/Temperature/Form"
    pathTo ResultAction = "/Temperature/Result"

data WebApplication = WebApplication deriving (Eq, Show)

data TemperatureController
    = FormAction
    | ResultAction
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data)

instance Controller TemperatureController where
   
    action FormAction = 

        let temp = Temperature { id = 0, farenheit = 100.0, meta = def }

        in
                
        respondHtml [hsx| {renderForm temp} |]

    action ResultAction = 
        let
            farenheit = IHP.ControllerPrelude.param @Float "farenheit"
            celsius = (farenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0
        in
            respondHtml [hsx| 
                <p>Celsius: {celsius}</p>
            |]

instance FrontController WebApplication where
    controllers = 
        [ 
          parseRoute @TemperatureController 
        ]

instance InitControllerContext WebApplication where
    initContext = do
        initAutoRefresh
```

Feel free to post other answers that demonstrate other perhaps more idiomatic approaches.